# Calculating size of content

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the code snippet. I have a file.

```
f = open(self.reportSavePath,'w')
self.test = '';
for file in file_sorted:
    f.write(str(os.path.getmtime(file)) + "|" + file + "\r\n")
    self.test = self.test + str(os.path.getmtime(file)) + "|" + file + "\r\n"
f.close()

print("Size:",os.path.getsize(self.reportSavePath)) #Without opening file
print("Calculated size:",len(self.test.encode()))     #After reading the contents
```

My question is, why are the last two lines giving different output? Should they not be same?

If there is a reason, how can I edit line with comment `#Without opening file` to match the output with line commented `#After reading the contents`?

Comment: You can see words like self because I have copied the snippet from my implementation. If question is unclear, please comment, I will try my best to edit and explain as much as possible to get your help

Comment: Will this return the same result, if file is opened in binary mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges.

`os.path.getsizeof` returns the file size. `len(some_string)` returns the length of the string in characters *regardless of encoding*, which can affect the naive byte count.

Comment: But is it not the same strings I am saving into the file?

Comment: @Romaan: the strings are the same, but as Yuval said, `len` gives you the number of characters in the string, whereas `getsize` returns the size of the file in bytes. One byte is not (necessarily) one character, just like one byte is not necessarily one second of music or one pixel of a bitmap image file.